# Perl use of array vs file

Tags: perl

Which of the following is a better way to write the code, considering impact on performance/time taken etc -
(Following is a pseudo code, please ignore syntax issues. Idea here is to understand under what circumstances to use an array vs a file )
Case 1::

```
@array; # globally accessible
sub 1 {
    #some operations on @array
}
.
.
.
sub 2 {
    #print @array info
}
```

Case 2 :: #instead of using array, use file

```
 sub 1 {
   #open file1
    #write to file1
    #close file
} 
.
.
.
sub 2 {
    #open file1
    #read file1
    #print file1 info
    #close file1
}
```

Comment: @Pri - Generally speaking: RAM operations (hence - array) will always be much faster then I/O operations (file).

Comment: Some notes: `@array;` is **not** a declaration. It is also not global. It creates a package variable if you do not have strict, but it doesn't really declare it during runtime, like `my` or `our` would. You cannot name subs `1` or `2`.

Answer (score 0):

*It depends on what you are going to do inside those subs*

The first example never makes sense in the given form ( wroten some operation on the array! you need to be specific).

If you are processing stuff sequentially, from beginning to end, it makes sense to use the file iterator instead of slurping it into memory, as by that way, you will not use as much system memory and perls buffering will handle the reading from the file in a relatively efficient manner.

***You should always process files line by line unless you can't otherwise avoid it***.

As soon as you need to go back and forth between lines, and jump backwards in the files, then the first approach of reading the whole file into memory makes the algorithm much easier to write (at the cost of some system memory).

If system memory is scarce and you are able to trade a bit of time against memory, take a look at [Tie::File](http://search.cpan.org/search?mode=module&query=Tie%3A%3AFile), which lets you access a file on disk just like an array in memory.

Comment: Best to avoid Tie::File, especially if you have memory issues. It's a huge memory hog. You could easily end up using more memory than the size of the file!

Comment: @ikegami what module you can advise to deal with files ?

Comment: I would work to avoid being in that situation in the first place (e.g. by re-ordering the data, by loading the data into a db, etc).